# Multiple custom UITableView cells, “Could not cast value of type ‘UITableViewCell (0x1e0487910) to ‘Page_Contents.CardCell’ (0x105b89be8)”

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a UITableView and three custom cells. I’d like every other row to have a different custom cell, with exception to the very first row being different from the rest. So, it would look like:

Cell type 1
Cell type 2
Cell type 3
Cell type 2
...

Here’s what I have so far.
When I run the Playground, I get the error:

> “Could not cast value of type ‘UITableViewCell (0x1e0487910) to
>   ‘Page_Contents.CardCell’ (0x105b89be8)”

I’m using Swift Playgrounds on iPad, so everything has to be done programmatically.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0{
            convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            let cell: CardCell = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")) as! CardCell
            //set the data here
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row%2 == 0{
            convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_2")
            let cell: BotResonse = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell_2")) as! BotResponse
            //set the data here
            return cell
        }else{
            convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_3")
            let cell: HumanResponse = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell_3")) as! HumanResponse
            //set the data here
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: convoTableView.frame.width, height: 100))

        header.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.97, green: 0.97, blue: 0.97, alpha: 1.0) 
        let yourLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        yourLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)
        yourLabel.text = "Kalm"

        let detailLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 200, height: 100))
        detailLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        detailLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        detailLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        detailLabel.text = "Let's be Friends"

        header.addSubview(yourLabel)
        header.addSubview(detailLabel)
        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 19
    }



    var convoTableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        convoTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
        convoTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        convoTableView.register(BotResponse.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_2")
        convoTableView.register(HumanResponse.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_3")

        self.convoTableView.delegate = self
        self.convoTableView.dataSource = self

        convoTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40.0
        convoTableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 40.0
        self.view.addSubview(convoTableView)
    }

}


// custom cell classes...

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

Comment: Not sure if related, but you don't have to re-register your cells inside `cellForRow`.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a couple things wrong...

Register the cells for reuse in `viewDidLoad()` (as you did), but ***NOT*** again in `cellForRowAt`.

In `cellForRowAt` you want to dequeue a reusable cell like this:

```
// NOT like this
let cell: BotResonse = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell_2")) as! BotResponse

// YES like this
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2", for: indexPath) as! BotResponse
```

Here is your code, modified to work (I included 3 empty cell classes (backgrounds get set to red, green, blue so you can see which is which):

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class CardCell: UITableViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

class BotResponse: UITableViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}

class HumanResponse: UITableViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0{

            // no no no
            //convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
            //let cell: CardCell = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")) as! CardCell

            // yes!
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell

            //set the data here
            return cell

        }else if indexPath.row%2 == 0{

            // no no no
            //convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_2")
            //let cell: BotResonse = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell_2")) as! BotResponse

            // yes!
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_2", for: indexPath) as! BotResponse

            //set the data here
            return cell

        }

        // no no no
        //convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_3")
        //let cell: HumanResponse = (UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell_3")) as! HumanResponse

        // yes!
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell_3", for: indexPath) as! HumanResponse

        //set the data here
        return cell

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: convoTableView.frame.width, height: 100))

        header.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.97, green: 0.97, blue: 0.97, alpha: 1.0)
        let yourLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        yourLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        yourLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        yourLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 32)
        yourLabel.text = "Kalm"

        let detailLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 30, width: 200, height: 100))
        detailLabel.textColor = UIColor.darkGray
        detailLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        detailLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        detailLabel.text = "Let's be Friends"

        header.addSubview(yourLabel)
        header.addSubview(detailLabel)
        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 19
    }



    var convoTableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        convoTableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: .plain)
        convoTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        convoTableView.register(CardCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        convoTableView.register(BotResponse.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_2")
        convoTableView.register(HumanResponse.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell_3")

        self.convoTableView.delegate = self
        self.convoTableView.dataSource = self

        convoTableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 40.0
        convoTableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 40.0
        self.view.addSubview(convoTableView)

        convoTableView.reloadData()
    }

}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```